# Start multiple activities from Notification via PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'd like to start multiple activities when press on Notification. I didn't find any docs about how to set multiple intents in a single `PendingIntent`.

One solution could be to start next activity in the first one's onCreate() and so forth, but I don't like this, maybe there is something else.

Comment: search for startActivities()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer for this - it's pretty trivial, just using method `getActivities()` to the `PendingIntent` like so:

```
        Intent myIntent1= new Intent(ctx, MyActivity1.class);
        myIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        Intent myIntent2= new Intent(ctx, MyActivity2.class);

        Intent[] intents = new Intent[]{myIntent1, myIntent2};
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(ctx, pid, intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: the same way I will write code but only myIntent2 only showing the notification myIntent1 one time also not execute