# One Notification Multiple Intents When app is killed

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, onesignal

I want to start **2 activities from 1 notification** .Actually ı want to open an activity when client click on the notification.Then if client press back button ı want to open second activity(main activity). multiple task flag is not working. I'm using OneSignal for notifications.Please help.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context2, ApplicationMakeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);                                                      
    context2.startActivity(intent);
```

This code block is working for my expectations if application is on background in API 21. If application is on kill state it is just opened my `ApplicationMakeActivity.class`    (for API 26 it is working like my expectations too)

PS: [Start multiple activities from Notification via PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942043/start-multiple-activities-from-notification-via-pendingintent) it is not working for me

PS2: adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"`to my manifest is not working too(I've add it to my `ApplicationMakeActivity.class` and `MainActivity.class` tags)

PS3:`<meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />' is added already in manifest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` to `ApplicationMakeActivity` in `AndroidManifest`

And add below lines when building notification

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(new Random().nextInt(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Use `setContentIntent(pendingIntent)` on `Notification.Builder`. It works.

Comment: Feel free if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your support.In this [link] I updated my codes.  (https://codeshare.io/5wK9n9)  Where is the problem? It is not working on  "Then if client press back button ı want to open second activity(main activity). " in this point. I'll kill myself..

Comment: What issues are you having? Do you wan't to open `ApplicationMakeActivity` when notification is clicked? Could  you post your full code and manifest.

Comment: You can read more about from this https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#java