# Android start two activites with single intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to start two activities with single intent

```
Intent[]  intents = new Intent[2];
 Intent i0 = new Intent();
i0.setClassName(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class.getName());


              Intent i1 = new Intent();
            i1.setClassName(this.getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class.getName());
            intents[1] = i1;


        intents[0] = i0;

  intents[intents.length - 1].putExtra(Constants.Intent.EXTRA_DATA, postLoginData);
        intents[intents.length - 1].addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

finish();
        startActivities(intents);
```

for some reason this wont work

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.tomatedigital.instagramgiveawaywinner/com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.activity.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

im sure it is in the manifest!!!!!!!!

if change the code and instead of insert two activities at the array i put only one (any of them) the code works normally

so what is the error

Comment: When you want to open first activity and when second one. Make them separately with if.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `PendingIntent` Class is the right way to do this.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent

Basically it works as a Stack. You can Add intents on it.

Example : [Start multiple activities from Notification via PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942043/start-multiple-activities-from-notification-via-pendingintent)